# Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge blank screen

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

Recently my S7 edge got blank screen and last thing I saw was samsung logo then it turned off and I don't see anything else only black screen. I tried using that vol up/down power/home force restart but device didn't respond it's fully charged and when I charge the phone fnothing shows up. I don't know if this is correct community for troubleshooting this kind of problem but I need help.

Comment: So by "force restart" you mean pressing the power button for a long time? If that has no effect the chance is high that you are facing a hardware defect.

Comment: @Robert no pressing volume down and power button for 20 seconds. I tried all variants of force restart e.g. pressing volume down, power button and home button for 20 seconds.

Comment: @alecxs even if battery dies and I connect to charger it doesn't show anything phone's state is unknown I don't know if it's on or off correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You don't know if it's on or off. disconnect the battery (or wait ~ 1 week until battery died)